# Rails Trying to Add a Record to Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am new to Rails. I am trying to duplicate a user from @users model, based on a match and then add it back in as a new row within the @users model. I am doing this as a quick one-off situation and doing it in the users_controller.rb

I have the following pseudocode --

`@users = users.includes(:products).order('orders.created_at DESC')`

`@new_user = @user.where(slug: "john-doe").first`

```
if !@new_user.nil?
  @new_user = @user.where(slug: "john-doe").first.clone
  @user << @new_user
end
```

However, within the view of the associated controller when I do the following --

```
<%= @new_user.inspect %>
```

It shows but when I do

`<%= @users.inspect %>`

It doesn't show @new_user actually added. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloning an object in ActiveRecord will create a new instance but will tie it to the same db record. ActiveRecord keeps state indicating it's relation to the db (like the primary key field (id) for example)

One way to create a clone is to copy the attributes you want over to the new instance:

```
a = @user.where(slug: "john-doe").first.attributes
a.delete('id')
User.create(a)
```

Comment: awesome! this seems to do the trick. question, how would i update the attributes of the new user I created?

Comment: never-mind i got it to work! thanks so much for the point in the right direction. its a.update